# how to make SoapUi request in powershell which requires header cookie?

Tags: c#, powershell, cookies

I have some web-service calls in soapui. I want to put them in a script so I can make them as monitor calls. Not sure what would be the best option to proceed. Thinking to write ps script to make those calls and use script to urn as a monitor. Please advice if you have a better suggestion. Appreciate your help!
- Sam

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you are asking but you can use `Invoke-WebRequest` to, well... invoke web requests.  You should be able to get that to work with WCF (I assume it is a WCF service since you are using SoapUI).

Comment: Do you have an working example for this? I tried using this cmdlet - didn't work. When I make the request from soapui it needs a header for cookie. If you can provide an example that would help to follow steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can send a SOAP request like this:

```
$soap = @"
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <Geocode xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts">
         <request xmlns:a="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Credentials xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common">
               <ApplicationId>ThisIsMySecret</ApplicationId>
               <Token i:nil="true" />
            </Credentials>
            <Culture xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common" i:nil="true" />
            <ExecutionOptions xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common" i:nil="true" />
            <UserProfile xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common" i:nil="true" />
            <a:Address xmlns:b="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common">
               <b:AddressLine>1747 Reynolds St NW</b:AddressLine>
               <b:AdminDistrict>TN</b:AdminDistrict>
               <b:CountryRegion i:nil="true" />
               <b:District i:nil="true" />
               <b:FormattedAddress i:nil="true" />
               <b:Locality>Knoxville</b:Locality>
               <b:PostalCode>37921</b:PostalCode>
               <b:PostalTown i:nil="true" />
            </a:Address>
            <a:Options i:nil="true" />
            <a:Query i:nil="true" />
         </request>
      </Geocode>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
"@

$headers = @{ 
    'Content-Type' = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'; 
    'SOAPAction' = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts/IGeocodeService/Geocode' 
}

Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Uri http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc `
    -Body $soap `
    -Method Post `
    -Headers $headers
```

If you need to add a cookie you can just add the string to `$headers`:

```
$headers = @{ 
    'Content-Type' = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'; 
    'SOAPAction' = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts/IGeocodeService/Geocode';
    'Cookie' = 'YouCookieGoesHere'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and getting this error:                                          + Invoke-WebRequest `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: PowerShell  version 3.0

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing your request.  Can you update your question with what you tried and the full error message.

Comment: $soap = @"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv= "http://sabc.." xmlns:v1="url....">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:FindUserName>
         <v1:UserName>myName</v1:UserName>
      </v1:FindUserName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@

$headers = @{ 
    'Content-Type' = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'; 
    'Cookie' = 'mycookie'
}

Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Uri url `
    -Body $soap `
    -Method Post `
    -Headers $headers

Comment: Perhaps you could try using the `ContentType` parameter rather than specifying the content type in the headers.

Comment: Yes.  Remove `Content-Type` from the headers hash table and use the `-ContentType` parameter on `Invoke-WebRequest` to specify the content type instead.  I have no idea if that will fix the problem but I have seen one or two posts somewhere else that seem to suggest there may be an issue in this area for earlier versions of PowerShell.

Comment: I am afraid I am out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks anyway for trying :)